# How to append more rows when scrolling to the Bottom with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's in *SharePoint* 2010, but I think It might run as it's normal.

**1**. The Item Limit per page is 30 as default. Thus, I have done with the list which showed 30 rows at the Page Load, then I have scrolled the mouse down to the Bottom and it hidden the last 10 rows.

**Summary**: Page loads 30 rows -> scroll down to the Bottom -> display 20 rows (hide the last 10-row).

Sorry for this inconvenience but it requires me to have at least 10 reputation to post images or more than 2 links.

Item Limit: [http://upanh.biz/images/2014/03/27/itemlimit.png]

When scrolling down to the Bottom: http://upanh.biz/images/2014/03/27/bottom.png

The list has changed: http://upanh.biz/images/2014/03/27/final.png

**The problem**: I do not know the way how to append 10 more rows when scrolling down to the Bottom of the page without re-loading this (the Item Limit can be modified to 100 items per page).

**Summary**: Page loads 30 rows -> scroll down to the Bottom -> display 40 rows

**Javascript** for **1**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#WebPartWPQ1 table table').eq(0).attr("id", "myNewTable");
$("#myNewTable tr").slice(30).hide();
var rowCount = $('#myNewTable tr').length;
//alert(rowCount);
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $("#myNewTable tr").slice(20).hide();
        alert("bottom");
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="WebPartWPQ1">
<div>
    <table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>something1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something5</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something6</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something7</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something9</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something10</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something11</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something14</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something15</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something16</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something17</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something18</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something19</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something20</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something21</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something22</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something23</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something24</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something25</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something26</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something27</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something28</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something29</td></tr>
            <tr><td>something30</td></tr>
            <tr><td>...more rows...</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </table>
    <table class="ms-bottompaging">something</table>
    <table id="Hero-WPQ1">something</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it'll work for u

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#WebPartWPQ1 table table').eq(0).attr("id", "myNewTable"); 
   $("#myNewTable tr").slice(30).hide(); 
   var rowCount = $('#myNewTable tr').length; 
   //alert(rowCount); 
   var y = 0;
   $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
      $("#myNewTable tr").slice(20).hide();
      var x = 0;
        /* Append next ten rows here */
        if(y < 20){ /* Maximum row you want to add*/
         for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
           x++;
           $("#myNewTable").append("<tr><td>something"+rowCount+i+"</td></tr>");
         }
         y += x;
        }else{
         return false;
        }
     } 
   });
```

If you want to display next 10 rows data from your database, then use the ajax() of jquery instead of for loop.

Comment: **@Smruti**: Thank you for your response. Now, it works but how can I stop it when it reaches to the last item? http://upanh.biz/images/2014/03/27/bottom1.png

Comment: when it reaches to the last item just use 'return false;'

Comment: **@Smruti**: Thank you, that is great. It returns the final result but it still loads more when I scroll down as the image below (1). How to stop loading more rows with the scroll bar? I really want to display some `<tr class=".." id="..."><tr>` as the image below (2)? **That means to append hidden rows in the `<table>`** http://upanh.biz/images/2014/03/27/bottom2.png

Comment: Before for loop provide a condition as if(rowcount < 45) means put the for loop within this condition. That will stop to append more rows.

Comment: **@Smruti**: I have tried it, but it did't work. Please take a look on it - Am I right? http://upanh.biz/images/2014/03/27/code.png

Comment: No dear, it's not right. I have edited my answer, Pls check it and let me know.

Comment: **@Smruti**: Thank you. I tried but It still didn't work. It still appends 31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40 without stopping when scrolling down.

Comment: Yes it appends data upto 45, bcoz we put the condition rowcount < 45. If you want to show upto 30, then instead of 45 you write 30. If any query then let me know.

Comment: **@Smruti**: That is Ok. Let me figure out it. I have one more problem that how I can display or append the hidden rows to the table instead of appending `append("<tr><td>something"+rowCount+i+"</td></tr>");` with number 2 in the picture: http://upanh.biz/images/2014/03/27/bottom2.png

Comment: .hidecls{display:none} add **hidecls** class in tr as append("<tr class='hidecls'><td>something"+rowCount+i+"</td></tr>");

Comment: **@Smruti**: It's also a good idea but I want to **un-hidden** rows of the table. Here is an example: http://upanh.biz/images/2014/03/27/code1.png (delete this style) and http://upanh.biz/images/2014/03/27/code2.png (a new blue line appears).

Comment: I got your answer, pls try the edited code now & let me inform