# JQuery - How to check if a tbody scrollbar has hit the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to get this working for some time and can't quite figure out. I did some search and found few posts on Stackoverflow. Based on those, I've attempted to make additional modification to the code snippet but so far everything unsuccessful.

Ref: [How to check if scrollbar is at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480466/how-to-check-if-scrollbar-is-at-the-bottom)

Ref: [How to append more rows when scrolling to the Bottom with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678474/how-to-append-more-rows-when-scrolling-to-the-bottom-with-javascript)

I have a table with few elements with limited height. There is a scroll bar. I need to trigger something only when the user scrolls to either TOP or Bottom.

Based on my research, I've been able to get the TOP part working, but not the BOTTOM.

```
 $('.tbody').scroll(function(event) {
   var height = $(this).height();
   var top = $(this).scrollTop();

   if ($(this).height() == $(this).scrollTop() + 1) {
     $("#msg").append('hit bottom <br>');
   }


   if (height - top == height) {
     $("#msg").append('hit top <br>');
   } else {
     console.log(top)
   }


 });
```

Please find my code here, https://jsfiddle.net/v58tvzL9/7/

If you scroll up and down, you'll see the scroll up working, but not down.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calculate if `scrollHeight - height` equals `scrollTop`

```js
$('.tbody').scroll(function(event) {
  var height = $(this).height();
  var top = $(this).scrollTop();

  if ($(this).get(0).scrollHeight - $(this).height() == Math.floor($(this).scrollTop())) 
  {
    $("#msg").append('hit bottom <br>');
  }


  if (height - top == height) {
    $("#msg").append('hit top <br>');
  } else {
    // console.log(top)
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  display: block;
}

.tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody class="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p id="msg">

</p>
```